# How to say (textbook) "exercise" in Japanese (school/university context)

Tags: words

How to say (textbook) "exercise" in Japanese, in the school/university context?

For instance, I would like to know how to say the following sentences:

(1) Today, we will only do this exercise.

(2) Please complete exercises 1) and 2) p. 203.

Is it possible to use the word 練習? What about エクササイズ? My dictionary also gives 演習. But here, I am only referring to exercises in a textbook, and not about the action of practicing an activity.

Comment: What about 問題 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a written exercise, 練習問題 or 演習 should be common. 練習問題 can be just 問題. For example,

1. 今日はこの練習問題(問題/演習)だけやります.
2. ２０３ページの１と２の練習問題(問題/演習)を終わらせてください.

練習 is more commonly used for something sportive as in

- サッカーの練習をしよう Let's train for soccer.

エクササイズ is also for activities, but I feel it's more for stretching, yoga, etc. In the context of language learning, I think 練習 or エクササイズ could be used for role-playing in dialogues.

Another related word is 例題, which can be used for exercises in textbooks. There is no strict distinction, but it tends to be 'a problem for explaining new things' and done in classrooms rather than independently by students.

Comment: Side question: how to say "exercise **number** two" ("Exercice 2)") ? Is it 第二の問題 ?

Comment: @starckman If it is textbook, 問題{もんだい}２{に} is the most common. 第二の問題 would be used if you are listing specific points about something (Fist, there is a problem of this. And, 第二の問題は..).

Comment: Thank you for the exhaustive explanation!